# why the integral of $\frac{dy}{y} =\ln(y)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I mean if I differentiate $\ln(y)$ the result will be $\frac{dy}{y}$ ? 
. What I know the diffential of $\ln(x)$ = $\frac{1}{x}$ right?. And following this idea what is going to happen if we differentiate $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: The differential of $\log(x)$ is $\frac{\operatorname{d}x}{x}, the derivative of $\log(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: If I differentiate $ln(y)$ the result is just $\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Differentiate $\ln y $ with respect to what?

Comment: What is the connection between y and x ?

Comment: I think you should change notation for derivatives when you are dealing with functions of one variable. Your notation with "differentials" might be really confusing.

Comment: @avati91 any example how can i change $\int \frac{dy}{y}$ to derivates notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot take the integral of $\frac{dy}{y}$, because the latter is not a function.  You can take the integral with respect to $y$, of $\frac{1}{y}$; we denote this as $$\int \frac{1}{y}~ dy$$

Note that the integral operator has a left symbol $\int$ and a right symbol $dy$.